# Dynamic Web Part Title URL

Tags: javascript, document-library

I would like to change the `Title URL field` of a `content editor` based on javascript.

I currently have a content editor that displays an Iframe of a document library.

How can I make the title of the content editor change to a hyperlink using javascript?

Using the below picture, I would like to click on "project documents" and have it take me to the document library shown.

[image]

Comment: Nate has already provided you with a solution, and it actually fits what you wanted to do. I would like to point out that I would avoid trying to change something that is formally **outside** the webpart - in a sense this seems like a violation of the single responsibility  patterns. I was wondering - wouldn't be simpler to just move the "link" inside the content editor web part and hide the web part chrome so that the original title isn't displayed?

Comment: honestly i really like this idea, going to try it out:)

Comment: Glad I could help. I won't probably post this a reply because the original question was pretty specific, but if this alternate solution works for you, it will be probably be better than trying to change the out-of-box title at runtime.

Comment: edit: I got this extra link to work, but I am not sure how to hide the title and make the new link sit in the correct spot

Comment: to hide the tittle, you have to go to the web part **Properties**, then under **Appearence** set the option **Chrome Type** to **None**. As for the position of the replacer link, you will have to work it out via CSS, based on you requirement

Comment: it looks like setting the chrome type to none makes my hillbillytabs unable to find the web part, unfortunately this won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accomplished this using jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var linkText = $(".ms-webpart-titleText").text();
        $(".ms-webpart-titleText").html("<a href='InsertURL'>" +linkText+ "</a>");
    });
</script>
```

You can place the script in a script editor above the content editor webpart.

Comment: I tried this, changing the code to(the CEWP im changing is webpartwpq21 as shown in dev tools): 
    
    var linkText = $("#WebPartWPQ21").text();
    $("#WebPartWPQ21").html("<a href=docLibUrl>" +linkText+ "</a>");

When I tried this, it didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Also, I don't think i will be able to use this... the url i enter into the <a> tag only allows me to append a url after: /sites/site1/sitePages/titleURLHere